# Getting folder path with space error - CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Tags: vbscript

How to deal with file path with space?
I tried use %20 as space but it doesn't work.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FolderPath="C:\My folder path\Target folder"    
Set myLog = fso.OpenTextFile(deleteLogFile, 2, True)                                                                            

GetRecentFile fso.GetFolder(FolderPath) '<-- I am getting error here                                                                                
DeleteFiles fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)   '<-- I am getting error here                                                                                

Function GetRecentFile(srcFolder)                                                         
  Set GetRecentFile = Nothing
  For Each file in fso.GetFolder(srcFolder).Files
    If GetRecentFile is Nothing Then
      Set GetRecentFile = file
    ElseIf file.DateLastModified > GetRecentFile.DateLastModified Then
      Set GetRecentFile = file
    End If
  Next
  LatestDate = GetRecentFile.DateLastModified
End Function
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Lankymart disagree.  `FolderPath="C:\My folder path\Target folder"` is right; if you use tripled quotes then you get `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found` on `fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)`… The issue isn't in quoting, definitely! The OP should give a [mcve] including full  error message.

Comment: @JosefZ you’re right, the error does suggest that is the issue though but the code doesn’t reflect it.